# Measuring size of websockets data input/output in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket, benchmarking

I'd like write a test to measure the size/amount of data being sent from a node.js server via websockets but I am not sure how to go about it. The messages are in JSON. Is there a way of measuring JSON size or any module that could help?

I'm sending a lot of data frequently and would like to measure the data throughput per second.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Consider an external tool such as Fiddler2 or Wireshark to observe *from the outside* (very easy to do for singular requests/sessions). There might also be some more specific network-monitoring tools/proxies that are designed to spit out such totals/reports.

Comment: @pst thanks. I've tried wireshark and chrome developer tools and I've mangaged to find the size of single messages but I would like to know the throughput over a sustained period of time.

Comment: What method are you using for sending the data?  On regular sockets, there is a callback when a send operation is completed, allowing you to make calculations at that point.

Comment: @Brad I'm using socket.io node.js module. There is a callback on message received by the client but is there a way of calculating the size of the message? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for throughput over time for a single page view?  After page load, you could calculate throughput by saving the HAR file from and extracting the relevant information.

Comment: @RobotEyes Are you interested in the total packet size or just the JSON size?  The browser receives JSON as a string so that's easy to calculate on the client side.  The server probably does JSON.stringify so you could replicate that and calculate it on the server side.  In both cases you could use tools to calculate the average header size and assume that it's fixed.

Comment: @BrianNickel that sounds like a good plan. Does measuring string size depend on character encoding?

Comment: Unlikely. It would come across as a JavaScript string.

Comment: You're not going to get a clear picture testing from within javascript.  The network level stuff can be as big as your message, and you'll only be able to measure that with something like wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the best way to do this is with a protocol analyser like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org).